# Javascript guards in multiple layers of application

Tags: javascript, types, parameters

Let say we have a function like this:

```
someFunc(item) {
  if (!item.itemType) return false
```

`item` parameter check is done in some other layer of application, so it "never" get `falsy` value. My approach is still to check it like this:

```
someFunc(item) {
  if (!item || !item.itemType) return false
```

Reason I always do every check is that other layer of application might change and it is not obvious to anyone that it is handled somewhere in code base. And, I don't want to dig through code base to actually confirm it.

Is my approach good in sense that every parameter check should be done and that we should always check for specific things, e.g. check if parameter type is array, object, null etc? I have this discussion with my colleague who prefer to do it like in first example.